# Filling and capping gap around round chimney liner

Tags: chimney

I would like to fill and cap the last few inches (is there a standard how deep?) between this r6" ound chimney liner and the bricks around it. I was planning to make a base with plywood that matches the currently empty space between, essentially a square with a 6.5" hole (leave 1/4" spacing) in the middle, suspend it a few inches below the top on 4 pieces of wire from two pieces of rebar sitting across the top of the chimney, them pour concrete on top.

[image]

Since the plywood base would be permanently trapped inside, my question is is plywood the correct material considering the general fire hazard of a chimney?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I'm no chimney pro

My brief research indicates that cement backer board seems to be pretty fire resistant, I'd suggest using that instead of plywood. While plywood *might* be sufficient, I'd think cement board would be better.

The strength of the cement board may be questionable when laid horizontally and expected to support weight, so maybe a doubled layer. If you're going to suspend it, maybe use eye bolts through both pieces of cement board with large fender washers on the bottom to spread the load and help keep it from breaking.

Comment: I think a single 1/2" cementboard should be plenty strong.

Comment: As noted, @amphibient, I'm no expert, so I'm covering my bases! ;)

Comment: being an "expert" doesn't mean jack to me

Comment: Unless you're gonna remove the bigger exhaust "thingy" at the top, you'll need to split your cement board to get it around the duct.  So you might as well double up like FreeMan suggests, but put the join lines perpendicular for each layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can **corbel** bricks or tiles mortared in place to reduce the gap, and you can support mortar or concrete on hardware cloth (galvanized or stainless steel wire mesh), so long as it's not too wet.

I would check the instructions for your chimney liner, as direct contact with mortar/cement may not be advised, (due to potential corrosion) and a metallic cap may be preferred or specified as a result.

Comment: i plan to leave a 1/4" gap between the liner and the cap to avoid direct contact

Comment: corbel? you mean to jut out buttresses from the chimney to support a plate on top? that would be harder to implement

Comment: No, in this case, jut **inwards**, to close the gap. You can also cast a plate off the chimney to be mortared on after it's cured.